# Passing params to tab navigator React Navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I’m using `materialTopTabs` and it seems like this loads all the screens in the navigator once its mounted. I have a screen **List** and inside it a tab navigator with 2 screens: **Posts** and **Users**. These two screen both depend on params passed from **List**. However, i am only able to pass params to one of the screens using this method:

```
navigation.navigate('PostsTabNav', {
  params: {
    network: item,
  },
  screen: 'NetworkPosts' //or NetworkUsers
});
```

I have tried to pass the params to my navigator directly by doing this:

```
navigation.navigate('PostsTabNav', {
  network: item
});
```

The first option only allows me to pass to one screen. The second option allows me to access the params inside the navigator like this:

```
const PostsTabNav = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const PostsMainNav = (props) => {
    const temp = props.route.params.network; //params here

    return (
        <PostsTabNav.Navigator>
            <PostsTabNav.Screen name="NetworkPosts" component={NetworkPostsScreen} />
            <PostsTabNav.Screen name="NetworkUsers" component={NetworkUsersScreen} />
        </PostsTabNav.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Is there a way to pass `temp` to both my screens? If not is there a better way to handle this situation?

Here's the code for the `StackNavigator`

```
const NetworkListStackNav = createStackNavigator();
export const NetworksListNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <NetworkListStackNav.Navigator>
            <NetworkListStackNav.Screen name="List" component={ListScreen} />
            <NetworkListStackNav.Screen name="PostsTabNav" component={PostsMainNav} />
        </NetworkListStackNav.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pass params to the navigator and then expose it to the tabs using React Context.

Create a context in a separate file which you can import in both your navigator and screens:

```js
export const NetworkContext = React.createContext();
```

Then provide the params in the context:

```js
const PostsTabNav = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const PostsMainNav = ({ route }) => {
  return (
    <NetworkContext.Provider value={route.params.network}>
      <PostsTabNav.Navigator>
        <PostsTabNav.Screen name="NetworkPosts" component={NetworkPostsScreen} />
        <PostsTabNav.Screen name="NetworkUsers" component={NetworkUsersScreen} />
      </PostsTabNav.Navigator>
    </NetworkContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

In your screen component, use the context:

```js
const network = React.useContext(NetworkContext);
```

Also see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation#passing-additional-props

Comment: is this the only way? Its pretty common scenario to pass data to props. Why there is only param to pass initial props?

Comment: The route is undefined, inside PostsMainNav function.

Comment: This seems a lot of work for just passing params to the tab navigator screens. Isn't there a better approach?

Comment: Another way is to use method 2 from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation#passing-additional-props using props: `<Stack.Screen name="Home">
  {(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={someData} />}
</Stack.Screen>`. Note that u need to remove `component` using this method

Answer (score 13):

You can set initial params to your screens.

```
const PostsTabNav = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const PostsMainNav = (props) => {
    const temp = props.route.params.network
    return (
        <PostsTabNav.Navigator>
            <PostsTabNav.Screen name="NetworkPosts" component={NetworkPostsScreen} initialParams={network:temp}/>
            <PostsTabNav.Screen name="NetworkUsers" component={NetworkUsersScreen} initialParams={network:temp}/>
        </PostsTabNav.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Comment: `initialParams` is never updated. So unless your params never change, this is a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function AppNavigator(props) {
    const { cartCount } = props;
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
              <Stack.Screen {...props} name="MainScreen" component={() => <MyTabs cartCounts={cartCount}></MyTabs>} options={{ headerShown: false }} countProp={cartCount} initialParams={{ 'count': cartCount }} />
             </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        cartCount: state.cart.cartCount,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(AppNavigator);
```

And your tab component like

```
function MyTabs(props) {
let cartCount = props.cartCounts;
return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
            tabBarStyle: { position: 'absolute' },
            tabBarStyle: styles.tabbarStyle
        }}>
        <BottomTab.Screen name="CartScreen" component={CartScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}
            options={{
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => (
                    <View style={styles.cartIconView}>
                        <Image
                            square
                            source={bottomCart}
                           
                        />
                        <Badge style={[GlobalStyles.badge, styles.count, {
                        }]}>
                            <Text style={[GlobalStyles.badgeText, styles.countText]}>{cartCount}</Text>
                        </Badge>
                    </View>
                ),
            }} />
    
    </BottomTab.Navigator >
);
```