# Unable to pass a param when navigation to a different tab

Tags: react-native, navigation, jsx, stack-navigator, tabnavigator

I have looked every related topic on StackOverflow without success.

I  am trying to go from a tab to another using "navigation.navigate" while passing a param. The navigation works but the param does not get passed.

here is what my TabNavigator looks like:

```
const handleTabPress = ({ navigation }) => {
  navigation.navigate(navigation.state.routeName);
  navigation.popToTop();
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Overview: {
      screen: OverviewStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Home",
        tabBarOnPress: handleTabPress,
        gesturesEnabled: false,
      },
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileStack,
      resetOnBlur: true,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Profile",
        tabBarOnPress: handleTabPress,
        gesturesEnabled: false,
      },
    },
....
```

And my profileStack looks like this

```
const MainProfileStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ...ProfileRoutes,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Profile",
    resetOnBlur: true,
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      ...SharedHeader(navigation),
    }),
  }
);

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ProfileMain: MainProfileStack,
  },
  {
    mode: "modal",
    headerMode: "none",
  }
);
```

Comment: You can refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61258731/passing-params-to-tab-navigator-react-navigation-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61258731/passing-params-to-tab-navigator-react-navigation-5). Please you mention the library and version.

Comment: I read that but didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use **redux** to share data.